# How to group in Laravel Eloquent by multiple distanced relationships (grouping by eager loaded relations)

Tags: laravel, eloquent, octobercms, laravel-query-builder

I have a relationship chain as follows:- A project `hasMany` Objectives each objective `hasMany` Outcomes and each outcome `hasMany` Outputs then each output `belongsTo` ir_indicator and each ir_idicator `belongsTo` ir and each ir `belongsTo` do.

I need to get all the projects `groupBy` the do name, to get a closer look to what i have worked with, checkout

```
    $ProjectsGroupedByDO = Project::has('objectives.outcomes.outputs.ir_indicator.ir.do')
->orderBy('created_at','desc')
->get()
->groupBy(function($d) {
         return $d->objectives->outcomes->outputs->ir_indicator->ir->do->name;
         }
    );
```

the problem is that `->objectives` , `outcomes`, `outputs` are all arrays because of the `hasMany` relationship that links them

How can I group my project with a distant relationship that is composed to layers of arrays?

NOTE: I am building this on OctoberCMS

Comment: A `project` can have multiple `do`s: Which one do you want to use for grouping?

Comment: @Jonas The idea I had in mind that it would use the `DO` `name` as a grouping field, for example (DO 1) => ['project 1', 'project 2'] , (DO 2) => ['project 3', 'project 4'] ...

Comment: But a `project` can have multiple `do`s, so multiple `name`s.

Comment: yes it can be under multiple groups .. for example (DO 1) => ['project 1', 'project 2'] , (DO 2) => ['project 1', 'project 4'], (DO 3) => ['project 3', 'project 2'] , (DO 4) => ['project 3', 'project 4']

Answer (score 1):

That's not what `groupBy()` is intended for. You have to build it yourself:

```php
$projects = Project::has('objectives.outcomes.outputs.ir_indicator.ir.do')->latest()->get();
$projectsGroupedByDO = new \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;
foreach($projects as $project) {
    $outputs = $project->objectives->pluck('outcomes')->flatten()->pluck('outputs')->flatten();
    $names = $outputs->pluck('ir_indicator.ir.do.name');
    foreach($names as $name) {
        if(!isset($projectsGroupedByDO[$name])) {
            $projectsGroupedByDO[$name] = new \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;
        }
        $projectsGroupedByDO[$name][] = $project;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting "Undefined index: Do 2" for some reason, unfortunately I am not getting the line where the error is actually happening cuz I am using OctoberCMS ( A content management system built over laravel).
However I think it is in the foreach cuz this is where we are using the Do Name

Comment: The technique only works on arrays but not on collections. I updated my answer.

Comment: I am getting "Undefined index: " nothing is written!, I am sure all my Do's have names

Comment: Put `print_r($names->all()); continue;` after the `$names = ` line. Are the values correct?

Comment: The third project's first name is the problem. Do all `outputs` have an `ir_indicator`? And all `ir_indicator`s an `ir`? And all `ir`s a `do`?

Comment: shouldn't the `has()` take care of that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178302/discussion-between-jonas-staudenmeir-and-ahmed-albarody).